# What are the differences between relationship and connection?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, definition

What are the differences between the words 'relationship' and 'connection?'

This is what I found in a dictionary: "A connection is a relationship between two things, people, or groups." Then, are they just the same? Is there any difference between a relationship and a connection that is used to indicate something between two people?

Comment: Did you look them up in a dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: This is written in a dictionary: "A connection is a relationship between two things, people, or groups." Then, are they just the same?  Is there any difference between a relationship and a connection that is used to indicate something between two people?

Comment: Including your research effort in the question improves it. Users are more willing to answer questions that show research effort. I edited your question to include your finding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connection between X and Y usually means one party can alter the state of the other party somehow, or deliver things quickly (such as information or supplies).

A relationship between X and Y simply means X and Y share some attributes, or possibly other things if X and Y are people.  X and Y might have a relationship but not a connection (e.g. John and Mark are Americans, but they live in other sides of the country and have never met, they are not connected).

The word *connection* is used if you can draw a line between two things.  This scheme is often visually used to represent a relationship and hence sometimes *connection* is used synonymously with relationship.

Comment: @ Lawrence.It is a complex question to be answerd.You have answered well.I struggled very hard to answer this question.Will you please have a look at my answer and comment..I am upvoting your answer

Answer (score 1):

I have referred to some on line dictionaries.connection and relationship seem to be synonymous and interchangeable in certain contexts.But they are not interchangeable some contexts.

**India and America have a  good relationship for the last 70 years.We can not say they have a good connection**

**The thieves have been arrested  in connection with a robbery**.

we can not use relationship year.

I have given some examples below to show the difference.

> **Relationship may refer to the connection because of blood or friendship.**

**How are you related**?

**We are cousins**

How are you connected?

We make research together.

They have connections with the thieves.

> **Connection may be positive or negative. we may have connection due to a bad a cause or a good cause.**

**I think relationship is 
usually positive.**

**We have  usualy relationship for a good cause**

Here are two links which help to know the difference or similarity between relationship and connection

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/relationship

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/connection